# Central Limit Theorem with gambles

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

I have this problem:

On each bet, a gambler loses 1 with probability 0.7, loses 2 with probability 0.2, or wins 10 with probability 0.1. Approximate the probability that the gambler will be losing after his first 100 bets.

My attempt:

Let $X_i$ be a random variable that denote the gambler’s winnings on the i-th bet.

Now,

$E(X) = -1(0.7) - 2(0.2)+10(0.1)=-0.1$, $E(X^2) = (-1)^2(0.7) - 2^2(0.2)+10^2(0.1)=11.5,
Var(X) = 11.5-(-0.1)^2 = 11.49$

Now, we are interested in the first 100 bets, thus,

$E(\sum_{i=1}^{100} X_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{100} E(X_i) = 100(-0.1) = -10$ and
$Var(\sum_{i=1}^{100} X_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{100} Var(X_i) = 100(11.49) = 1,149$

Therefore,

$P(X<0) = P(\frac{X+10}{\sqrt{1,149}}<\frac{10}{\sqrt{1,149}}) = P(Z<\frac{10}{\sqrt{1,149}}) = \Phi(0.295) = \Phi(0.295)=0.6141$

Am I right? I think that there is a problem saying that $P(Z<\frac{-10}{\sqrt{1,149}}) = \Phi(-0.295)$ because $P(Z\leq x) = \Phi(x)$

Comment: Common sense indicates since the gambler is losing on *average*, his chances of losing after 100 bets are higher than 50%, not lower. (This doesn't hold in general but it does here)

Comment: There seems to be a simple sign error at $P( \frac{X + 10}{\sqrt{11.49} }< \frac{ \textbf{+10}}{\sqrt{11.49}})$ - the rest of the solutions looks correct on first sight.

Comment: I think more precise calculations, not using a normal approximation, give a probability of being behind after $100$ attempts of about $0.6213329$, of breaking even of about $0.0118386$ and of being ahead of about $0.3668285$.  You will not get these with a normal approximation, but you should be reasonably close

Comment: Right, I already corrected the sign as @AlexanderGeldhof said and I got 0.6141, that is close to the value that Henry said.